# How do I COPY or MOVE Outlook folders from Outlook to Sharepoint?

Tags: outlook, migrate

How do I copy or move Outlook folders from Outlook to Sharepoint.  HOW?

Comment: You want store emails in sharepoint library?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I was able to sync in Windows (not Mac) by going into the SharePoint list, click the List menu item and "Connect to Outlook." The prompts helped me do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging-and-Dropping to Outlook Folders.

Using left-click to drag-and-drop will MOVE the email to SharePoint (i.e. it will be deleted from the Inbox). Right-clicking presents a menu that enables you to choose COPY, MOVE or CANCEL. For more information on how to set this up to manage email, see Managing Email.

This May Work.